# Creating a very custom list

Tags: android-studio

I'm developping an application, and now, I don't know what to do next:
I have a list of elements, each element has some informations + an ID + a logo.
What I want to do is creating a list like in the picture

[List](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fp3Ch.png)

Of course, I want it in a single layer, with the logo, some informations, and a button to define an action; where I could use the ID of the selected item.

I did some research, may be I found some relative subjects, but none of what I want.

My list is a

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>
```

filled by data from database.
Thank you

Comment: you need to use a custom listview or a recycler view

Comment: Thanks ! I'm on Android Studio, how could I define thos custom listview, and also defin diffrent component of an item?

Comment: where did you stored the logo means images

Comment: It's a link image available with those informations

Comment: that link  represents only a view , I am asking you that does you stored images on web server or in sqlite

Comment: Ah, everything is on a web server, the Id, the infos but, i'll get the image with a model internet link including the ID of the item (http finishing with .jpg).

Comment: check this tutorial helped me http://www.androidhive.info/2014/07/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text-using-volley/

Comment: I will, thanks a lot !

Comment: Well, very well, finally could modify as I like, it is perfect to me; but, how could I set an action onClick on each item on the list?
"and a button to define an action; where I could use the ID of the selected item."

Comment: Post the code you tried so I will suggests edits

Answer (score 0):

Here it is:

```
public class Avancee extends Activity {
    // Log tag
    private static final String TAG = MainActivity2.class.getSimpleName();

    // Movies json url
    private static final String url = "http://blabla.com/movie.json";
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    private List<Movie> movieList = new ArrayList<Movie>();
    private ListView listView;
    private CustomListAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        adapter = new CustomListAdapter(this, movieList);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        // Showing progress dialog before making http request
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        pDialog.show();
        // changing action bar color
        getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(
                new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#1b1b1b")));

        // Creating volley request obj

        JsonArrayRequest movieReq = new JsonArrayRequest(url,
                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {

                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                        //Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
                        hidePDialog();

                        String result = getIntent().getStringExtra("ITEM_EXTRAA");
                        System.out.println(result);
                        try{
                            JSONArray ja = new JSONArray(result);
                            for (int i = 0; i < ja.length(); i++) {
                                try {

                                    JSONObject obj = ja.getJSONObject(i);
                                    Movie movie = new Movie();
                                    movie.setTitle(obj.getString("title"));
                                    movie.setLocation(obj.getString("location_search_text"));
                                    movie.setId(obj.getInt("id"));


                                    // adding movie to movies array
                                    movieList.add(movie);

                                } catch (JSONException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }

                            }
                        }catch(JSONException e){
                            Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
                        }

                        // notifying list adapter about data changes
                        // so that it renders the list view with updated data
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                hidePDialog();

            }
        });

        // Adding request to request queue
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(movieReq);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        hidePDialog();
    }

    private void hidePDialog() {
        if (pDialog != null) {
            pDialog.dismiss();
            pDialog = null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

It's the "id" that I want to get in the OnClick event.

Comment: Found it ! if someone has to do the same, modify in the file CustomListAdapter.java in this sheet:
`TextView id = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.releaseYear);



  
  final Movie m = movieItems.get(position);
  RelativeLayout entreprise = (RelativeLayout)convertView.findViewById(R.id.entreprise);
  entreprise.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onClick(View view) {
    //USING m.getWhatUWant
   }
  });`

Answer (score 0):

use this code

```
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {

Movie movie= movieList.get(position);

            }
        });
```

//here position will give you the id of listview cell so you can use it like 
Movie movie= movieList.get(position);
then you can use it get all the data inside your moview object